# IOS IPAD Not Displaying Input type="image"

Tags: html, ios, css

We are using input type="image" for a paypal link on our cart -> check out page and it is not displaying on IPAD. I'm assuming this is because IOS likes to override form elements. Does anybody have any experience with this?

I tried to attach an screen capture but stack overflow says I'm too big of a noob.

Comment: Try using a styled <button> with javascript to submit?

Comment: We're hoping for a css solution as this is an ASP project that would require a build to fix. If it's not possible we'll have to go that route.

Comment: How small is the button? Can you give it `-webkit-appearance:none;
border-radius: 0;` if yes this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263260/stop-safari-mobile-from-giving-input-buttons-rounded-corners

Comment: It's an image so webkit appearance and border radius is not going to apply here. When I searched for solutions I've found that I seem to be the only one experiencing this.

Comment: Can you provide more info/code? What is the reason for using `<input type="image">` over styling a button or input tag with the image? Is this a webpage or a html5 webview app?

Answer (score 0):

This question is several years old, but just in case someone stumbles on this - I had the same problem, and it was a matter of making sure the image URL was hosted under https. Then it worked.