# some buttons show up as circles on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios

I am creating an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe game and some of the buttons show up as circles  on an iOS device.
[here is a link to the wiki page for this game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tic-tac-toe)

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

here is the iOS screen shot( ipad and iPhone):
[image: iOS]

here is the first row HTML:
It has the the topmost games.  the other rows are similar

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="111" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="112" class="grid vert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="113" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="211" class="grid rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="212" class="grid vert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="213" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="311" class="grid  rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="312" class="grid vert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="313" class="grid"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="121" class="grid hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="122" class="grid vert hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="123" class="grid hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="221" class="grid hori rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="222" class="grid vert hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="223" class="grid hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="321" class="grid hori rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="322" class="grid vert hori"></button></td>
                <td><button id="323" class="grid hori"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="131" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="132" class="grid vert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="133" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="231" class="grid rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="232" class="grid vert "></button></td>
                <td><button id="233" class="grid"></button></td>
                <td><button id="331" class="grid rightVert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="332" class="grid vert"></button></td>
                <td><button id="333" class="grid"></button></td>
            </tr>
```

CSS:

```
 .grid{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vert {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
.hori {
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
.rightVert {
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
.topHori {
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

found an answer here:
[Stop Safari Mobile from giving input buttons rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263260/stop-safari-mobile-from-giving-input-buttons-rounded-corners)

added

```
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
```

to the .grid css

Comment: This has been bugging me for ages, and yours was the only solution that worked :)